# Google File Picker: Fix return to root folder comes up empty

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, filepicker, google-picker

In my JS file picker implementation, I am successfully able to download files successfully, and navigate through the folder structure.  However, if I return to the root folder after navigating away from it, nothing is displayed:

View implementation:

```
    const createView = () => {
        const google = google || window.google;
        // show all docs
        const view = new google.picker.DocsView();
        // include the ability to see & navigate folders
        view.setIncludeFolders( true );
        // constrain file types to those accepted for upload
        let mimeTypes = '';
        const acceptedTypes = [
            ...Globals.acceptedSharedDocumentFileTypes,
            ...Globals.googleFileMimeTypes,
        ];
        for ( const type of acceptedTypes ) {
            if ( acceptedTypes.indexOf( type ) < acceptedTypes.length - 1 ) {
                mimeTypes += `${ type },`;
            } else {
                mimeTypes += type;
            }
        }
        view.setMimeTypes( mimeTypes );
        // view as list instead of GRID
        view.setMode( google.picker.DocsViewMode.LIST );
        return view;
    };
```

Picker Implementation:

```
    const initFilePicker = () => {
        // open the file picker
        const google = google || window.google;
        const view = createView();
        const picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            .addView( view )
            .setOAuthToken( authObject.access_token )
            .setDeveloperKey( googleKeys.web.api_key )
            .setCallback( handlePickedFiles )
            .build();
        picker.setVisible( true );
    };
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you have a look at the developper console when nothing is displayed? Most likely threre is an error.

Comment: If you're referring to the browser dev console, no errors are showing

Comment: And how do you return to the root folder?

Comment: It turned out the problem was related to navigating into and out of shared folders.  activating the shared folders feature solved the problem.